# Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(1-z)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

So I see this in my book:

[image]

So the first one I understand is the power series representation of a geometric series right?

But what is the second? Is the second just showing that this is an alternative representation of $\frac{1}{(1-z)}$ with negative powers and that's what makes it a laurent series? Since there are only negative powers in the second representation, that's what makes it a Laurent series right?

The two are different representations of the same series correct?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).  Please use MathJax to
$\color{yellow}{\rm highlight}$ the math expression instead of posting images.

Comment: For example, $$\bbox[yellow,2pt]{\text{highlight}} $$ math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically correct.  The two series have different regions of convergence:  the first on $|z|\lt1$, the second $|z|\gt1$.  They are both Laurent series.  The first happens to be a Taylor series,  as well.  They are both around $z=0$.

I wouldn't say  they are representations of the same series, but rather the same function on different regions.

Comment: So the second series is a representation of that geometric series when |z| > 1. Is that a correct thing to say?

Comment: I'd still rather say a representation of the _function_, $1/(1-z)$.